# If $A$ is idempotent and symmetric, then $A=BB^T$ where $B^TB=I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is idempotent and symmetric, then $A=BB^T$ where $B^TB=I$.

I know that since $A$ is symmetric, then it is positive semidefinite, i.e.

$x^TAx\ge 0 \forall x$,

then there is a $B$ such that $A=B^TB$.

But isn't this true only if $A$ is of full rank?

Comment: are you saying all symmetric matrices are positive semidefinite?

Comment: @lightfish : what you are trying to prove is false.  $A$ can be the zero matrix.  Where did you get the question?

Comment: symmetric and idempotent is positive semidefinite?

Comment: when do you say a matrix is idempotent?

Comment: I'm working through Searle's Matrix Algebra Useful for Statistics Chapter 11 problem 18

Comment: Can you at least see that there exist a matrix $B$ such that $BB^T=A$  without the condition $B^TB=I$?

Comment: I know a symmetric matrix can undergo eigendecomposition into $B\Lambda B^T$ but not sure what kind of decomposition would get $BB^T$.

Comment: I am just asking can you find $B$ such that $BB^T=A$ using definition of idempotence and symmetric nature of $A$?

Comment: If I assume $B^TB=I$, then can I write $I=A^{-1}A=B^TB$ implies
$A^{-1}A^2=B^TB$ implies
$A^2A^{-1}=BB^T$ implies
$A^{2-1}=BB^T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not true.

$A=0$ is idempotent, as $0^2=0$. If $A=BB^T$ and $B^TB=I$, then $$I=B^TBB^TB=B^T(BB^T)B=B^TAB=B^T0B=0.$$

Try also,
$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{matrix}\right).
$$
Then $A^2=A$. If $A=BB^T$ and $B^TB=I$, then 
$$I=B^TBB^TB=B^T(BB^T)B=B^TAB,$$
which implies that $A$ is nonsingular - contradiction.

However, assuming that $A$ is non-singular, then $A^2=A$ implies that $A(A-I)=0$, and in turn that
$$
A-I=A^{-1}A(A-I)=A^{-1}0=0,
$$
and hence that $A=I$.

Comment: is there a solution for $A\neq0$??

Comment: I guess the question is for non zero matrices.. for zero matrices idempotency and symmetric nature would not be very interesting....

Comment: See updated version.