# Decomposition of idempotent and symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In [Patterson and Thompson, 1971](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2334389) I find the following claim which I cannot prove myself, nor have I been able to find a proof:

> "As $S$ is idempotent and symmetric [*and of size $n\times n$ and with rank* $=n-t$], it can be expressed in the form $AA'$, where $A$ is an $n \times (n - t)$ matrix such that $A'A = I$."

My questions are: How do I prove this, and can the matrix $A$ be computed in a straightforward way?

I note that almost the same question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635990/if-a-is-idempotent-and-symmetric-then-a-bbt-where-btb-i) and the answer accepted. However, if I understand it correctly that answer claims to prove the statement false, and that does not seem reasonable to me. I believe that answer considers square matrices $A$? Anyway, any help appreciated.

Comment: The linked question does not answer your question. All the counterexamples listed there are examples of a lower rank. Also, since you are talking about symmetric matrices, you too are considering square matrices.

Comment: No, perhaps my statement was unclear, but I am saying that the matrix I denote A (denoted B in the other question) is considered square in the proof in the other question (I think, but am not 100 % sure). In my question, A is n x (n-t) for t>0. Also, the matrix S in my question is not of full rank but of rank n-t, where t>0.

Comment: Do you know if the matrix is positive-definite?

Comment: If the matrix is real, the result follows rather easily from the spectral theorem.

Comment: No, I believe positive definiteness cannot be assumed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supposing we are working on the field $\mathbb{R}$, $S$ can be written as $PDP^T$, where $P$ is an orthogonal matrix and $D$ is diagonal. We further suppose that the $n-t$ nonzero diagonal elements of $D$ are at the top-left.

Let's remark that since $PDP^T=S=S^2=PD^2P^T$, any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $D$ satisfies $\lambda^2=\lambda$, so that $\lambda=1$ or $\lambda=0$. Therefore, any nonzero eigenvalue of $S$ is $1$, and we get that

$$S=QQ^T,$$

where $Q$ is the $n\times (n-t)$ matrix obtained by keeping the first $n-t$ columns of $P$. Furthermore, we have $Q^TQ=I_{n-t}$ since $P$ is orthogonal.

Comment: Thanks, that solves it in a clear manner.